# How can I get a reference to an instance of an object passed via lambda expression?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, lambda

for WPF binding issues, i'm trying to find out how I can get a reference to an object instance being passed in a lamba expression.

I have created a new class "CustomBinding"' thta can take a lambda expression as argument and extract the source and path from it. This works well if the lambda that is 
being passed has it's referenced property within the same caller class:

```
public class CustomBinding : Binding
{
    public CustomBinding(Expression<Func<object>> expr) : base()
    {
        Source = (expr.Compile().Target as Closure).Constants[0];
        Path = (expr.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name;
    }
}


public class A
{
    public string MyProperty { get;set;}

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        var workingbinding = new CustomBinding(()=>MyProperty);
        .....
    }
}
```

But what if the lambda expression is using the property of another object. How can I get a reference of that object ?

Like this :

```
public class B
{
    public void MyOtherMethod()
    {
        var otherObject = new A();
        var nonworkingbinding = new CustomBinding(() => otherObject.MyProperty) 
                //this fails, the Source is not set correct
    }
}
```

How can I extract a reference to the "otherObject" instance from the lambda expression ?

Comment: What if there is no object in use? It is legal to call `CustomBinding` like this `CustomBinding(() => new object())`. What you would expect `reference to  passed object` to be in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple way for objectName.PropertyName:

```
//Get Target Object
object targetObject = null;
var memberExp = expr.Body as MemberExpression;
var bodyExp = memberExp.Expression;
if (bodyExp != null)
    targetObject = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(bodyExp).Compile()();   
else if (isStaticProp)
    targetObject = memberExp.Member.DeclaringType;
else
    throw new Exception("Could not determine target object.");
```

The hard way for devil's expressions like evilObjects[12].ActualObject.ActualProperty:

```
public static object GetContainer<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyLambdaExpression)
{
    return Evaluate((propertyLambdaExpression.Body as MemberExpression).Expression);
}
public static object Evaluate(Expression e)
{
    switch (e.NodeType)
    {
        case ExpressionType.Constant:
            return (e as ConstantExpression).Value;
        case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:
            {
                var propertyExpression = e as MemberExpression;
                var field = propertyExpression.Member as FieldInfo;
                var property = propertyExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;
                var container = propertyExpression.Expression == null ? null : Evaluate(propertyExpression.Expression);
                if (field != null)
                    return field.GetValue(container);
                else if (property != null)
                    return property.GetValue(container, null);
                else
                    return null;
            }
        case ExpressionType.ArrayIndex: //Arrays
        {
            var arrayIndex = e as BinaryExpression;
            var idx = (int)Evaluate(arrayIndex.Right);
            var array = (object[])Evaluate(arrayIndex.Left);
            return array[idx];
        }
        case ExpressionType.Call: //Generic Lists and Dictionaries
        {
            var call = e as MethodCallExpression;
            var callingObj = Evaluate(call.Object);
            object[] args = new object[call.Arguments.Count];
            for (var idx = 0; idx < call.Arguments.Count; ++idx)
                args[idx] = Evaluate(call.Arguments[idx]);
            return call.Method.Invoke(callingObj, args);
        }
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Then just call GetContainer(expr).